# Strange Function Call behavior

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am quite new to Fortran and I was 'playing' with functions.
I found a quite weird behavior in a very simple program that I cannot justify in any way.  Here is the simple code:

```
Real*8 Function gamma(v)
 Implicit None
 Real*8 :: v
 gamma = 1.0_8 / Sqrt(1.0_8 - v ** 2)
End Function gamma

Program test_gamma
 Implicit None
 Real*8 :: v = 0.5_8, gamma
 print *,"Gamma = ", 1.0_8 / Sqrt(1.0_8 - v ** 2)
End Program
```

This prints the exact result: `1.1547005383792517`
but if I use the function call, doing the same calculation, `print *,"Gamma = ", gamma(v)` I have the unexpected result `1.7724538509055161`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: thanks, yes i add gamma in the declaration, `Real*8 :: v = 0.5_8, gamma` but the result does not change. I think the function is never called for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 1.7724538509055161 corresponds to the (correct) result from the (mathematical) gamma function with argument 0.5.  The standard intrinsic function `gamma` returns result corresponding to this gamma function.

In your program calling `gamma` you have declared gamma to return a `real*8` result, but you haven't given it the `external` attribute, or made an interface available through other means.  So, the intrinsic is to called instead: when compiling the main program the compiler "knows" about no alternative  [I'd expect a compiler warning in such circumstances if you ask for it.]

I'd recommend that you call your function something other than `gamma` rather than add the `external` attribute.  I'd even recommend that for a function which has an interface available in the program.

By "interface available", I mean you could:

- put your `gamma` function *internal* to the main program;
- put your `gamma` function in a module `use`d by the main program;
- [offer an interface block.]

Consult your programming guide for details.

Finally, I'd also recommend one other thing: no `real*8`.  You can read many comments here on SO about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i did not know Fortran had a builtin gamma function.

Comment: It was newly added in the 2008 standard.  Technically, then, my answer isn't so valid for the [tag:fortran90].

Comment: It is still valid, the function was a common vendor extension (which are allowed by the standard) before and the error wound happen the same way.