# Ignoring the intrinsic gamma function with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Ok, so I am using this old Fortran code that has defined a function that has nothing to do with the mathematical gamma function with the name gamma.

Apparently, in the older Fortran versions, there was no intrinsic gamma function. But when I compile and run the code with gfortran, instead of using this user-defined gamma function, the code actually uses the new intrinsic gamma function.

Is there a way for me to make the user-defined gamma function supersede the intrinsic one? I'd like to modify the code as less as possible, ie. not rename the user-defined gamma function everywhere.

I tried using the flag `-std=legacy` in the makefile, but it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187658/strange-function-call-behavior/27188172#27188172 (the same problem).

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
 EXTERNAL GAMMA
```

to the scoping unit that uses `GAMMA`.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an intrinsic with the same name as an external procedure then there are two ways to say that you want to reference the external rather than the intrinsic:

- using the `external` statement/attribute;
- providing an explicit interface for the external procedure.

Using an `external` statement or attribute would be most in keeping with "old code".  However, simply declaring the function with, say, `real gamma` would [not suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27187658/3157076).

```
  implicit none
  real, external :: gamma
  print*, gamma(1.0)
end
```

This `external` attribute says that the intrinsic function is not to be used (and provides an implicit interface for the function).

Alternatively, if there is an explicit interface for a non-intrinsic function available then this function will be used instead of the intrinsic:

```
  use my_external_functions, only : gamma
  implicit none
  print*, gamma(1.)
end
```

Or you can use an interface block.

That is, you can create a suitable explicit interface and make that available.  Some would say that this is a nice thing to do anyway, but would be much more invasive in changes to your legacy code.

---

I have, of course, used free-form source and `implicit none` in this answer.  If you are modifying older code, and are happy being less strict, then:

```
      external gamma
      print*, gamma(1.)
      end
```

---

For the case where the intrinsic procedure is a non-standard extension, you additionally have the option of asking the compiler to disable such extensions. For example, the gfortran flag `-std=f2018`, and such, requests stricter conformance to the language revision specified, removing the interpretation of a non-standard intrinsic.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help!